# Steam game installation without steam? (Closed)

Tags: steam, 32-bit

I have a 32 bit system and as you know the recent steam update screwed over anyone with a 32 bit system, as the only thing they can access is the settings and the library. I can't go into the steam store in the app. How will I install new games?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I tried that but when buying games it opens the app and the with the store being unavailable to me there is nothing I can do

Comment: If you have the android app you can remotely download games from the app in the library section